# Different PHP-FPM Pools for frontend and backend using Apache2

Tags: magento-1.9, apache2, php-fpm

I found [this article](https://tideways.com/profiler/blog/seperate-your-slow-backend-from-the-important-frontend-traffic-with-php-fpm) teaching how to create two different php-fpm pools from magento frontend and backend using nginx.

My question is: is it possible to do this using Apache2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

sure

you just read how it works in here:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html

then in apache `frontend` vhost config you add something like this:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html/ 

<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
    <FilesMatch \.(phtml|php)$>
            SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

then in apache `backend` vhost config you add something like this:

```
  <VirtualHost 4.3.2.1:443>
    ServerName admin.example.com

    DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html/

<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
    <FilesMatch \.(phtml|php)$>
            SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```